# Regular Expression to Match Multiline Comments

Tags: c#, regex, comments

I've been trying to match comments in a HTML file using regular expressions and remove them completely through a C#.net (VS2010) solution.
Here's how comments look like,

```
/*This flexibility is not available with most other programming languages. E.g. in Java,
the position for \G is remembered by the Matcher object.
The Matcher is strictly associated with a single regular expression and a single subject
string.*/
```

I did try `/\*.+\*/`,

```
str = File.ReadAllText("Test.html");<br />
str = Regex.Replace(str, "/\*.+\*/", "", RegexOptions.Singleline);<br />
File.WriteAllText("Test.html", str);
```

But they were not working out for me. I've followed some answers in the forum, but still no luck.

I'd appreciate any help :)

Thanks...

Comment: Are you searching for c# comments in your HTML? because then you need to select everything that's between a `/*` and a `*/` ?

Comment: No Izzy, it's comments in a HTML file :)

Comment: dont html comments look like this <!-- comment --> ? :D

Comment: @RaheelHasan That's why I was confused :)

Comment: Some of 'em were. I've managed to remove 'em but left ones with /* ... */.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to add an extra layer of escaping in your string literal:

```
str = Regex.Replace(str, "/\*.+\*/", "", RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

produces `/*.+*/` as a pattern because `\` is the escape metacharcter of c# string literals.  you need to specify it using one of the follwing variants (`@` prevents processing of escape sequences, `\\` should be self-explanatory ...):

```
str = Regex.Replace(str, @"/\*.+\*/", "", RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

or

```
str = Regex.Replace(str, "/\\*.+\\*/", "", RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

Comment: Thank you Collapsar :) Works perfectly. Thanks again for explaining what is it all about.

Answer (score 0):

To find `/*comments*/`, try this regex:

```
/\/\*.+?\*\//ims
```

Comment: It's returning an error in VS: Unrecognized escape sequence

BTW Thanks Raheel :)

Comment: Welcome :D did you try `@` to prevent escape sequence being processed themselves?..

Comment: Oh... Just try using @ but still leaving comments in the file mate.